# Объявление/определение и статическое поле класса С++

Tags: c++

Есть класс с двумя статическими полями

```
struct S
{
    static int a; 
    static const int b = 1;      
};
```

Чтобы иметь возможность использовать поле S::a напрямую или создать указатель на него, необходимо определить это поле вне класса в глобальной области видимости.

```
cout << S::a << endl;        // ошибка
int* ptr_a = &S::a;          // ошибка

int S::a = 1;                // обязательное условие, теперь:
cout << S::a << endl;        // ок
int* ptr_a = &S::a;          // ок
```

Получить же значение статического константного поля можно, а вот инициализировать указатель - по-прежнему нет.

```
cout << S::b << endl;        // ок
const int* ptr_b = &S::b;    // ошибка (undefined reference to S::b)
```

Способ исправить это простой: дописать определение вне класса.

```
const int S::b;              // этого уже будет достаточно, теперь
сonst int* ptr_b = &S::b;    // ок
```

Поясните, пожалуйста, эту тонкость. Если можно использовать значение статического константного поля S::b напрямую без дополнительного определения вне класса, то где это значение хранится? Или оно напрямую подставляется при компиляции, не помещаясь в память, и поэтому линкер выдает ошибку 'undefined reference'?

***** UPDATE 1 *****

Пока печатал вопрос, часть ответа сама нашлась. Точнее, нашлась идея посмотреть ассемблерный код. Действительно, значение подставляется напрямую - [пример](https://godbolt.org/z/1d9xEje94). Надо выяснить остальное

***** UPDATE 2 *****

Начинать, как оказалось, необходимо с уточнения, что такое "объявление/declaration" и что такое "определение/definition". Сам вопрос содержал много ошибок в терминологии (исправил их) и, разобравшись с терминами, получилось разобраться и с самим вопросом.

Ответ на английском [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410632)
Также смотрел в черновике [N4868](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4868.pdf) (главы 6 и 9)

Если вкратце отвечать на собственный же вопрос - оба поля, приведенный мной являются только лишь объявлениями, но не определениями.

```
struct S
{
    static int a;             // объявление
    static const int b = 1;   // тоже объявление!
};
```

Однако, поскольку поле b является константным, его значение можно использовать напрямую без определения и без выделения памяти (см. update 1). Ну а поскольку определения нет, то получить указатель невозможно = получаем ошибку линкера.

Отдельная благодарность господину [Alex Guteniev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/403913/alex-guteniev) за указание на то, что static constexpr является определением.

По главе 6.2 пункту (2.20) стандарта и собранным ответам [набросал пример](https://godbolt.org/z/8r8rEYh8T).

Comment: *"Статическое неконстантное поле не может быть определено внутри самого класса."* - это неверно. "*Статическое константное поле, наоборот, можно сразу же инициализировать внутри класса.*" у вас `b` не определено, оттого и нельзя делать ссылки или указатели на него.

Comment: @user7860670 может быть определено с помощью inline: `static inline int a = 1;` ? Или Вы о чем-то другом? Или я некорректно использую слово _определить_?

Comment: Вы пишите *"не может быть определено"*, а теперь пишите "*может быть определено*"...

Comment: @user7860670 в вопросе я привел формулировку, которую именно в таком виде усвоил когда-то из учебника и сейчас просто достал из памяти. А когда Вы сказали, что _это неверно_, приступил к поиску, что именно в этой формулировке неверно. Подумал на `inline`. Вы могли бы объяснить, как дела обстоят в действительности?

Comment: Обычные поля структуры хранятся внутри **каждого** объекта. А статические поля в единственном экземпляре внутри глобальных переменных в **единственном** экземпляре. Попытка получить адрес отсутствующей переменной даёт ошибку компиляции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Определение вне класса требуется для ODR-use (не знаю русскоязычного термина).

> Или оно напрямую подставляется при компиляции, не помещаясь в память

Да. Использование константы времени компиляции не является ODR-use.

Начиная с C++17:

- Для `static constexpr` членов не обязательно определение вне класса, даже если они ODR-used.
- Для `static inline` членов  не нужно определение вне класса.

Comment: Спасибо, Вы дополнили то, что удалось накопать к этому моменту. Оказалось, что, первым делом, надо было разбираться с тем, что такое "объявление" и "определение". К сожалению, из первого учебника усвоил (мало того) поверхностную (так еще) и неправильную информацию. Проапдейчу вопрос позже примерами и ссылками на стандарт